# Convert regular CURL request to Multi CURL request

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I have the following CURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "websiteURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("
    Content-Type: application/json",
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("XXXXX:YYYYYY")
));

for ($i=0; $i < 300; $i++){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"src": "'.$numbers_from[$i] ['number_from'].'","dst": "'.$messages[$i['international_format'].'", "text": "'.$current_message.'"}');
    $message = curl_exec($ch);
}

curl_close();
```

How would it be using  Multi CURL ? What is the alternatives of these functions using multi CURL ?

Answer (score 0):

Example taken from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```